# Запись результата матриц в .txt файл

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Matrix
    {
       
        private int n;
        private int[,] mass;

      
        public Matrix() { }
        public int N
        {
            get { return n; }
            set { if (value > 0) n = value; }
        }

     
        public Matrix(int n)
        {
            this.n = n;
            mass = new int[this.n, this.n];
        }
        public int this[int i, int j]
        {
            get
            {
                return mass[i, j];
            }
            set
            {
                mass[i, j] = value;
            }
        }


        public void WriteMat()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите элемент матрицы {0}:{1}", i + 1, j + 1);
                    mass[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }

      
        public void ReadMat()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(mass[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }


      
        public void oneMat(Matrix a)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (a[i, j] == 1 && i == j)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (count == a.N)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Единичная");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Не единичная");
        }


    
        public static Matrix umnch(Matrix a, int ch)
        {
            Matrix resMass = new Matrix(a.N);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.N; j++)
                {
                    resMass[i, j] = a[i, j] * ch;
                }
            }
            return resMass;
        }

        
        public static Matrix umn(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            Matrix resMass = new Matrix(a.N);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.N; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < b.N; j++)
                    for (int k = 0; k < b.N; k++)
                        resMass[i, j] += a[i, k] * b[k, j];

            return resMass;
        }



        
        public static Matrix operator *(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            return Matrix.umn(a, b);
        }

        public static Matrix operator *(Matrix a, int b)
        {
            return Matrix.umnch(a, b);
        }


     
        public static Matrix razn(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            Matrix resMass = new Matrix(a.N);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b.N; j++)
                {
                    resMass[i, j] = a[i, j] - b[i, j];
                }
            }
            return resMass;
        }

       
        public static Matrix operator -(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            return Matrix.razn(a, b);
        }
        public static Matrix Sum(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            Matrix resMass = new Matrix(a.N);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b.N; j++)
                {
                    resMass[i, j] = a[i, j] + b[i, j];
                }
            }
            return resMass;
        }
       
        public static Matrix operator +(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            return Matrix.Sum(a, b);
        }
       
        ~Matrix()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Очистка");
        }

    }
    class MainProgram
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите размерность матрицы: ");
            int nn = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
         
            Matrix mass1 = new Matrix(nn);
            Matrix mass2 = new Matrix(nn);
            Matrix mass3 = new Matrix(nn);
            Matrix mass4 = new Matrix(nn);
            Matrix mass5 = new Matrix(nn);
            Matrix mass6 = new Matrix(nn);
            Matrix mass7 = new Matrix(nn);
            Matrix mass8 = new Matrix(nn);
            Console.WriteLine("ввод Матрица А: ");
            mass1.WriteMat();
            Console.WriteLine("Ввод Матрица B: ");
            mass2.WriteMat();

            Console.WriteLine("Матрица А: ");
            mass1.ReadMat();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Матрица В: ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            mass2.ReadMat();

            Console.WriteLine("Сложение матриц А и Б(C): ");
            mass4 = (mass1 + mass2);
            mass4.ReadMat();

            Console.WriteLine("Вычитание матриц А и Б(C): ");
            mass6 = (mass1 - mass2);
            mass6.ReadMat();

            Console.WriteLine("Матрица C по формуле (2*А-5*В): ");
            mass7 = ((mass1 * 2) - (mass2 * 5));
            mass7.ReadMat();
            string path = @"d:\MyTest.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(mass1);
                    sw.WriteLine(mass2);
                    sw.WriteLine(mass4);
                    sw.WriteLine(mass6);
                    sw.WriteLine(mass7);

                }
            }

            
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Добрый день,столкнулся с одной проблемой,нужно результат матриц отобразить в текстовом файле,как при выведении в консоли,пытался попробовать сам,но вместо этого выводит имя группы.

Comment: `sw.WriteLine(mass1);` чтобы это работало надо перегрузить метод `toString()` вашего класса.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь!